# MySQL: save SELECT to variable

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have** something like this:

```
SELECT FROM table
WHERE field NOT IN (
    SELECT FROM other_table ... //SECOND QUERY
)
```

**Problem:** I don't want `SECOND QUERY` be executed for each row of `table`. Can I save `QUERY 2` result to some variable?

Comment: Do `other_table` and `table` have anything in common?  Maybe using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` could be better?  Or a `JOIN`?

Comment: Why do you think the subquery will be executed multiple times?

Comment: it won't be executed for every row of table. MySQL will run the subquery and save the results of that in memory (if possible) or in disk (if not). I would recommend making this a NOT EXISTS query as opposed to a NOT IN query though. The later should be more efficient. You can verify by using EXPLAIN to determine the Query Execution Plan

Comment: You can use a NOT EXISTS clause. But I would hope that the query engine is smart enough not to run the subquery for each row ;)

Comment: This query is running use set theory, not a cursor or for loop. It wouldn't execute for every row in the first table.

Comment: @juergend is mysql so clever that it calls `QUERY 2` only one time?

Comment: @RocketHazmat actually the second query is the chain of joins

Comment: @V_B so clever... hmmm, that's just his job ;)

Comment: @V_B It seems you don't understand the difference between imperative and  declarative programming languages. SQL is declarative, this means that it is up to the DBMS to figure out the most effective way to (imperatively) execute the queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the query will run for every row by running `EXPLAIN` and looking if it its a `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` or `SUBQUERY`. Dependent will run for each row.

Based on that you want to 'save it to a variable' I'm guessing it will not be dependent.

If you want to save a resultset to a 'variable' you need to use a temp table. In this case it will not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A LEFT NULL JOIN may be a lot faster for you.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table AS t
  LEFT JOIN other_table AS ot ON ot.field = t.field
    WHERE ot.field IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't see why this would be faster.

Comment: @popovitsj he said that it *may* be faster. MySQL's query planner usually works better with joins.

Comment: Yes, this way just a possibility for the poster to try.  Any possibilities should be examined using EXPLAIN.